# What is this "reversed" connector called?

Tags: connector, plug, coupler

Looking at this power connector, what is its name? It's kind of a "reversed" form of the standard IEC 603 C7/C8 coupler.

Also, what could be the rationale of the manufacturer not to use the standard coupler?

[image: not quite C7/C8]

Just to be complete, the device is a TP-link TL-WR710N Wifi Router.

I want to get a cable connecting a type C plug to the device to be able to plug it in farther away from the wall box.

Comment: It's unlikely you'll find a cable to match that.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use a standard extension cord?

Comment: For the sake of practicality, it's of course the easier option. But I was wondering what (or if) this is standardized as.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what the connector is. My guess is that it's intentionally nonstandard -- precisely to prevent users from doing what you are trying to do, that is, install it off of a wall.

Why would they want to do that? My best guess for that is to *improve RF performance*. Check out page 3 of the [user guide](https://static.tp-link.com/resources/document/TL-WR710N_V2_User_Guide_1910010956.pdf), it has an FCC statement with some interesting troubleshooting info, including:

- Reorient or relocate the receiving antenna.
- Increase the separation between the equipment and receiver.
- Connect the equipment into an outlet on a circuit different from that to which the receiver is connected.

My guess is that the device has been designed (power of the radio, antennae orientation) such that it works best for when it's installed upright on a wall. This probably optimizes the radiation pattern, improving the received/transmit power to your devices.

The third point relates to your question and I believe it is to prevent RF noise interference/coupling. WiFi is electromagnetic radiation so it can be affected by transients caused by a variety of sources, and those sources increase as you move the device away from its own dedicated wall outlet and onto, say, a power strip.

The strip might have switches to turn it on and off, not great shielding, etc. which would cause problems for the router. It's a bit handwavy because I don't fully understand what this specific cause may be, but I do know that these are some possible factors. Hope that helps!

Comment: wow, nice answer, thanks for all the good points! could have been so smart to look up the user guide myself, I feel a bit dumb now.

So, that it has a coupler at all is probably to save costs on the international market then.

Comment: Haha I have *never* actually read that FCC statement on anything I have ever owned until researching this question. Thanks for bringing me there! :)